# Input file accept attribute not working

Tags: javascript, html

I want the user to select these files listed in the accept attributes. But its not allowing the user to select ***.mov** files. I am not sure why.
Given below is the html I have used.

```
 <input type="file" tabindex="0"
                    accept="video/mov, video/3g2, video/3gp, video/3gp2, video/3gpp, video/asf, video/asx, video/avi, video/divx, video/m4v,  video/mp4, video/mpe, video/x-m4v, video/mpeg, video/mpg, video/ogg, video/wmv"
                    name="video">
```

I couldn't find much after googling. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, given that the MIME type for [QuickTime movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime_File_Format) (`.mov` or `.qt` files) is `video/quicktime` and that's not in your list... :-)

MIME types are not just a category followed by a file extension. `video/mov` isn't, to the best of my knowlege, a defined MIME type. I'd also double-check `video/3g2`, `video/3gp`, `video/3gp2`, `video/asf`, `video/asx`, `video/avi`, `video/m4v`, `video/mpe`, `video/mpg`, and `video/wmv`, as I'm not sure any of those is a defined MIME type.

Answer (score 11):

Try `video/quicktime`

See https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/MIMETypeRegistry.cpp for webkit MIME types

Comment: exactly what am I looking for. Thanks you